# Variables are being reset, but effects are not taking place

Tags: java

I am programming a game, but I have ran into an error.

When the player collided with an object, `player.hasCollided` is set to true.

```
if(playerBounds.intersects(wolfBounds)){
        player.hasCollided = true;  
        player.dead();
}
```

Now, when hasCollided is true, something from the LoseScreen class is printed out onto the screen:

```
if(player.hasCollided){
        lose.start(g);
}
```

In player.dead(), the player's speed is set to 0.

```
public void dead(){
    playerSpeed = 0;
    coinBank += coinsCollected;
}
```

The problem is that in my InputHandler class I make it so that on the lose screen, when the choice is 1, and enter is pressed, restartGame() is called.

```
public void restartGame(){
        obstacleWolf.getNewPosition();
        obstacleHole.getNewPosition();
        hasLost = false;
        player.hasCollided = false;
        player.playerSpeed = 5;
        player.nextX = 1000;
        player.coinsCollected = 0;
        player.xElapsed = 0;
}
```

```
if(lose.choice == 1 && enter){
            game.hasLost = false;
            game.restartGame();
            System.out.println(player.hasCollided + " " + player.playerSpeed);
}
```

Those variables ARE being set to what they are meant to be set to (for example playerSpeed becomes 5 from 0, and hasCollided is becoming false from true) but the effects are not taking place. So, like I showed before, lose.start(g); is only meant to be called when hasCollided is true, but even when it becomes false, it is still printed out on the screen.

Here is how the relevant variables/methods are being used:

```
public void move() {
    x = x - player.playerSpeed;
}
```

(All moving objects share the same move method)

Parts of the game class:

```
public void tick(){
    input.tick();

    if(gameState){
        player.tick();
        player.move();
        collision();
        treeline.move();
        obstacleHole.move();
        obstacleWolf.move();
        coin.move();
        coin.tick();
}
```

I am not sure if I can make this question clearer. I can provide more code from different classes if needed.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I think you need a smaller question -- describing this one fully is going to take a lot more effort.  There are too many things that affect what's going on that you don't show, and in fact would have trouble showing in a reasonable amount of space and time.  Try to debug your code to the extent that you have a smaller question -- why a method isn't getting fired, why a variable set in one place doesn't seem to have the correct value another place, something like that.

Comment: I third the suggestions to work towards providing *less* code that is *more relevant*. Use more of the debugger, notably the ability to set field breakpoints that print a message to the console when a value is changed. That will let you see whether the flag is being reset somewhere or if it's being set on a completely different object than the one you're reading it from.

Answer (score -2):

The question can't be answered in its current form (see 2 comments above).
The reason for that is current code structure.

You need to refactor code, then you will find the problem.
Put all modification of player fields in methods of Player class.
Access fields only through methods. Making fields private is old good practice.
Then the only code you need to share would be this Player class.

In one thread environment, that's all.

Comment: -1: "You need to start fixing your code then your code will be fixed" is not an answer. Refactoring code is also at best indirectly useful in that you end up gazing at it long enough to maybe spot the issue. A systematic diagnosis by debugging and isolating the problem would be better.

Comment: I disagree. Currently even to see Player related code is already problem. Also as Andrew Thomson mention using SSCCE term (which is nice), the quetion in its current form can't be unswared without leavings all code. Though only player.hasCollided means related code should be only in Player, otherwise it is bad design.

Comment: I agree that the question as is is unanswerable. That's why you shouldn't have answered, and asked for clarification instead / flagged the question / something. Bad questions don't excuse bad answers. And while the excessive coupling in what we see of the OP's code isn't great, it's not the **immediate cause** of the OP's problem. Precisely *because* the code shown and information provided doesn't contain that problem's cause. (Even if it might have ultimately lead to it, but even then your suggestion can very well be a wild goose chase since it's more about your design sensibilities.)